# WHERE clause in OPEN QUERY

Tags: sql, sql-server, oracle, oracle11g

I have created a procedure in SQL Server 2012 for the purpose of fetching the yesterday data from an Oracle table and inserting it into a SQL Server table
using OPENQUERY like this:

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#Temp') IS NOT NULL
     DROP TABLE #Temp 

SELECT   
    LEAD(CONVERT(VARCHAR, CONVERT(DATETIME, '01-JAN-1970 03:00:00', 120) + [DAT_CLOSEDATE] / (24 * 60 * 60), 120), 1, CONVERT(VARCHAR, CONVERT(DATETIME, '01-JAN-1970 03:00:00', 120) + [DAT_CLOSEDATE] / (24 * 60 * 60), 120)) OVER (PARTITION BY [TXT_TICKETNUMBER] ORDER BY [DAT_CLOSEDATE]) AS [CLOSE_DATE]
INTO 
    #Temp
FROM
    OPENQUERY(ORACLE_DB, 'SELECT DAT_CLOSEDATE, TXT_TICKETNUMBER FROM SCHEME.TABLE')
WHERE       
    [DAT_CLOSEDATE] = DATEADD(d, -1, GETDATE())
```

Everything is working as expected, but the problem in the SQL Server syntax is within the `WHERE` clause, so that I want to make it inside the `OPENQUERY` considering the following:

1. `DAT_CLOSEDATE` must be dynamic fetching the yesterday data (today-1)
2. The `DAT_CLOSEDATE` column data type in Oracle is `FLOAT` and `DATETIME` in SQL Server

I expect `OPENQUERY` syntax to be something like the following:

```
OPENQUERY(ORACLE_DB, 'SELECT DAT_CLOSEDATE, TXT_TICKETNUMBER   
                      FROM SCHEME.TABLE 
                      WHERE [DAT_CLOSEDATE] = DATEADD(d, -1, GETDATE())')
```

Comment: You should add some sample data here, to make your requirement clearer.

Comment: What do you mean "The DAT_CLOSEDATE column data type in Oracle is FLOAT"?  How is a date/time being stored using a `float`?  Of course, the data model should be fixed in Oracle, but more important for your question is what the data actually looks like.

Comment: I am searching too much to join where clause in OpenQuery and this is really help,

Answer (score 1):

If looking for an equivalent on Oracle then:

```
where DAT_CLOSEDATE = sysdate-1
```

or

```
where DAT_CLOSEDATE = trunc(sysdate)-1
```

The second version sets the time of day to 00:00:00

Comment: the DAT_CLOSEDATE column data type is float

Comment: Well why not include that in the question? Do you know how that column translates into a date?

Answer (score 0):

*Suppose* `DAT_CLOSEDATE` *column has float type values such as* `20181231202534`, `20181231202713` ... *that is, they're of type* `yyyymmddhh24miss` *converted from a date value, where `yyyy` stands for `year`, `mm` for month, `dd` for day, `hh24` for hour in the range of `00-23`, `mi` for minute, and `ss` is for second.*

*In this case, [the following](https://rextester.com/MCDUXA72901) block might be invoked :*

```
OPENQUERY(ORACLE_DB, 'SELECT DAT_CLOSEDATE, TXT_TICKETNUMBER   
                        FROM SCHEMA.MYTABLE 
                       WHERE substr(DAT_CLOSEDATE,1,8) = to_char(sysdate-1,''yyyymmdd'')')
```

*to get the values of the previous day.*