# Query yesterday data from oracle db using SSMS

Tags: sql, sql-server, oracle, t-sql, oracle11g

I faced a problem in fetching the yesterday data from oracle 
I use OPENQUERY to fetch the data from oracle as following:

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#Temp') IS NOT NULL
    DROP TABLE #Temp

    SELECT   [TXT_TICKETNUMBER] AS [TICKET_NUMBER]
            ,CAST(lead(convert(varchar,convert(datetime,'01-JAN-1970 03:00:00',120) + [DAT_CLOSEDATE]/(24*60*60), 120),1,convert(varchar,convert(datetime,'01-JAN-1970 03:00:00',120) + [DAT_CLOSEDATE]/(24*60*60), 120)) over(partition by [TXT_TICKETNUMBER] order by [DAT_CLOSEDATE])AS date) AS [CLOSE_DATE]

    INTO #Temp
    FROM OPENQUERY(RUHRTTSDB, 'SELECT * FROM ARADMIN.RTTS_HPD_TROUBLETICKET')
    WHERE   [DAT_CLOSEDATE] = SYSDATE - 1
```

Comment: Well, after 3 failed attempts I throw in the towel. Hope someone else will be able to help...

Comment: The first step is to write a query that works using only Oracle tools when directly connect to the Oracle server. Once you have that it should be a simple task to convert that using  Openquery. SQL Server will not understand SYSDATE - that would need to go into the query that is passed to Oracle. And passing that where clause to Oracle will make the query much more efficient. Otherwise (speaking logically), SQL Server would need to pull back all the rows from the query before evaluating the date condition.

Comment: And learn to ask smart questions. You "face a problem" but you never explain what problem you encountered. Did an error occur? If so, post the complete error message (and not just an image). Something else? Communicate

Comment: And looking back in your history, it seems you have already encountered this [problem previously](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53993938/where-clause-in-open-query) and have suggestions and complications caused by your schema.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [WHERE clause in OPEN QUERY](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53993938/where-clause-in-open-query)